# Change axis label Color (JFreeChart)

Tags: jfreechart

Can anyone tell me how I can proceed to change the color of the axes' labels as circled below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setTickLabelPaint()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setTickLabelPaint-java.awt.Paint-) and [`setLabelPaint()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setLabelPaint-java.awt.Paint-) like this:

```
Axis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
domain.setTickLabelPaint(Color.blue);
domain.setLabelPaint(Color.blue);
Axis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
range.setTickLabelPaint(Color.red);
range.setLabelPaint(Color.red);
```